# How to use <a> instead of a button on express.js post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am using handlebars as my templating engine and I use buttons to call `app.post()` on my javascript file.

```
<form method="POST" action="/smo_assessment">
<div class="container" id="div1">
    <h3 id="header" align="center">Request Inventory</h3>
    <h4 style="color: white">Select the ID of the request you want to make an assesssment</h4>

    <table>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" style="width: 80px" name="requestID">
            {{#each requests}}
            <option>{{this.id}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button buttontype="submit" class="btn btn-default" id=btn1>Make Assessment</button>
    </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

However, since I am using `bootstrap navbar`, I need to use a `<a>` tag instead of a button in order to navigate to a different page.

```
app.post('/smo_assessment', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id=?', req.body.requestID, function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else 
            selectedRequest = rows  

        res.render('smo_assessment', {assessmentType, data: selectedRequest[0]});   
    });

});
```

Comment: Just curious: why are you using post at all? If you have control on server side `GET /smo_assessment/:id` looks more reasonable.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko I'm a newbee, how do you use .get(/page) when you click a button or link on your front end?

Comment: Just change `app.post` to `app.get` if you want to use `GET`. In your particular case, `GET` seems more appropriate as you are retrieving things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`form.submit()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) Javascript method:

```html
<form id="theForm" method="POST" action="/smo_assessment">
<div class="container" id="div1">
    <h3 id="header" align="center">Request Inventory</h3>
    <h4 style="color: white">Select the ID of the request you want to make an assesssment</h4>

    <table>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" style="width: 80px" name="requestID">
            {{#each requests}}
            <option>{{this.id}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('theForm').submit();" class="linkSubmit" id="linkBtn1">Make Assessment</a>
    </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your form and use it into a on-click event:

```
<form id="myForm">
  ...
  <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="myForm.submit();">Make Assessment</a>
</form>
```